# MacOS : brew install package throws a proxy issue in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, proxy, wget

I am banging my head trying to find out from where is the proxy being read from.

Here is the background. I am trying to do `brew install wget` on the Mac terminal

However, I immediately get `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/': Failed to connect to xxxxproxy.proxy.proxy.com port 8080: Connection refused`

I tried to remove the HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, ALL_PROXY, http_proxy, https_proxy, all_proxy. When I run `echo $xxxxx_proxy` for all the above variables, I get blank values, indicating that the proxies are unset.

Where is this proxy being read from? Any help/guide would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: I might have posted a very silly question, or maybe the question is a duplicate (which I am not able to find here). If so, I apologize in advance :)

Comment: How do you remove the variables? `http_proxy=""` or `unset http_proxy`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov - I used `export HTTP_PROXY=` in the terminal. After reading your comment, I also tried to use `unset HTTP_PROXY`, but still the same result.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `.gitconfig` file in my home `/Users/<username>/.gitconfig` had the proxy values set within it. As soon as I commented those, everything started working smoothly.

```
 #[http]
 #   proxy = xxx.xxx.xxx.com:80
 #[https]
 #   proxy = xx.xxx.xxx.com:80
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `brew` package behind a proxy you should set variable `ALL_PROXY`

```
export ALL_PROXY=proxyIP:port
```

If you want to remove the proxy definition and use direct connection execute in terminal:

```
unset ALL_PROXY
```

and in the same terminal execute the command